# Retrieve start time and end time in jQuery Week Calendar to store in database

Tags: jquery, python, tornado

Currently i am working in time sheet project.I am using https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar  .I need calculate total hours. so i getting form elements to store database for manipulation. I am fresher only . I am not familiar in jQuery at all.
I am using python to getting form elements. when i try get start and end time, It prints

```
Date : Jan 09, 2015 Start Time : Fri Jan 09 2015 09:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) End TImeFri Jan 09 2015 09:15:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)  Hi
```

display timesheet.py

```
page.addcontent('<form action="/create_timesheet" method="post">')
page.addcontent('<input type="hidden" />')
page.addcontent('<ul>')
page.addcontent('<li>')
page.addcontent('<span>Date: </span><input name="date" type="text"  class="date_holder"/>')
page.addcontent('</li>')
page.addcontent('<li>')
page.addcontent('<label for="start">Start Time: </label><select name="start"><option value="">Select Start Time</option></select>')
page.addcontent('</li>')
page.addcontent('<li>')
page.addcontent('<label for="end">End Time: </label><select name="end"><option value="">Select End Time</option></select>')
page.addcontent('</li>')
page.addcontent('<li>')
page.addcontent('<label for="title">Task Category: </label><select name="title">')
page.addcontent('<option value="">Hardware Testing</option>')
page.addcontent('<option value="">Software Testing</option>')
page.addcontent('<option value="">Unit Testing</option>')
page.addcontent('<option value="">Verification Testing</option>')
page.addcontent('<option value="">Software Development</option>')
page.addcontent('<option value="">Web Development</option>')
page.addcontent('</select>')
page.addcontent('</li>')
page.addcontent('<li>')
page.addcontent('<label for="body">Body: </label><textarea name="body"></textarea>')
page.addcontent('</li>')
page.addcontent('<br><button type="submit" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">save</button>')
page.addcontent('</ul>')
page.addcontent('</form>')
```

timesheet_hanler.py

class NewTimesheetHandler(FrameworkHandler,RequestHandler):

```
def process(self):
    Date = self.get_argument("date","")
    StartTime = self.get_argument("start","")
    EndTime = self.get_argument("end","")
    Title = self.get_argument("title","")
    Body = self.get_argument("body","")
    print Date,StartTime,EndTime,Title,Body
    #return self.static_url('/display_timesheet')
    return self.render_template("display_timesheet.py")
```

My Question is I need to print only start and End time . i.e.; If i select Start Time 1:00PM and End Time 3:00 PM . I need to print only 1:00PM and 3:00PM.

Comment: And where is the question ?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Question updated